# winui3 change ilistviewitem image on mouse over , selected unselected - list view control

Tags: listview, listviewitem

am working on winUi3 application.  am using mvvm pattern.   have one listview and created data template for that. every listviewitem will display image. if user mouse hover  have to display one image and removed we have to display another image. similarly for selected, selection changed events as well.

want one sample using MVVM pattern.